# Animation in physical device

Tags: android, animation

I have a zoom in and then zoom out animation for a text in my activity that runs very good in emulator, but when I run it on real physical device animation is not good, problem is not animation speed, problem is what happened in this picture:

[image]

In addition in emulator when text be zoomed it's background is transparent and doesn't affect other elements, but in physical device it's background automatically become white and has overlapping effects on other adjacent elements. totally everything is good on emulator.Does anyone have any same experience that could help me? [my zoom animation:]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:zAdjustment="normal"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:duration="500"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%" >
</scale>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:fromXScale="2.0"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:zAdjustment="normal"
    android:fromYScale="2.0"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:duration="500"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%" >
</scale>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical device appears to have a lower density than the emulator.

At the moment it looks like you are only supplying *one version* of the graphics, but in reality you should be supplying *four or five* versions of the graphics to enable support at different densities.

Here's a picture which illustrates your issue. Straight from the Android docs. The second example has 'good support' for image densities... take note of the size of the graphics - **they are all consistent. That's best practice**

[image]

You could force Android to use one density, but the problem is your actual-device graphic would probably end up looking microscopically tiny, but on a different device be gigantic. It's a very discouraged approach, particularly because you can't anticipate on how any of your designs will look because of how wildly they will all vary due to the forced-single-density

I highly recommend reading **everything** on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

As for your background, I'm not sure but it sounds like you haven't correctly specified a background, or are trying to achieve some kind of transparent affect, which isn't compatible on all devices, or specifically *is* compatible on your emulator but *not* your device.